# How to turn off the responsive feature completely from Twitter Bootstrap 3?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I turn off responsiveness in Bootstrap 3?

I just want to develop a desktop version and when the size is different it should still appear like the desktop version.

Twitter.com does this. If you try to resize, nothing happens to the UI while my site is redesigning all the elements.

Example of how I want it:
[image]

Anyway now how to turn off the responiveness? All help appreciated.

Also recently read that in Bootstrap 2.0 you just remove responive boostrap CSS, but in 3.0 its baked into one css file.

Thanks.

Comment: Just use `.col-lg-` inside `.row`, not `.col-sm`  or `.col`. Other thing you can do is simply search for `@media` calls and delete them and all inside.

Comment: thanks for you reply. im using .col-lg- inside of a .row already, still it goes to responive. also tried to delete the @media things. no difference thought.

Comment: The `.col-lg-X` and `.col-sm-X` classes change widths and stop floating at different media widths. You want to stick to the plain `.col-X` classes, which always float and have constant percentage widths that don't change based on media. See if my answer below is what you are looking for.

Comment: With the 3.0 full release, the Bootstrap team added a section to the docs describing how to achieve this: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive

Answer (score 46, accepted):

**EDIT:** My code below was written for v3.0.0RC2, but in v3.0.0 the docs got a section specifically about this question: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive

Use the `col-xs-X` classes since they are constant percentage widths. Then the responsiveness comes from `.container` using `max-width` at different media sizes. You can define your own alternative to `.container` and use everything else like normal:

Fiddle for the example below: http://jsfiddle.net/xTePL/

HTML:

```xml
<!-- Don't use .container at all or you will have to
     override a lot of responsive styles. -->
<div class="container-non-responsive">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <h1>Welcome to Non-responsive Land</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-8">
      <!-- More content, more content -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.container-non-responsive {
  /* Margin/padding copied from Bootstrap */
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;

  /* Set width to your desired site width */
  width: 1170px;
}
```

Comment: With v3.0.0RC2 the col-X classes should be replaced with col-xs-X

Comment: This doesn't do anything. Can't you just set a width on .container and be done?

Comment: @Moss Nope.  Don't know why yet, but just setting the width won't do it.  Ssorallen's answer worked like a charm, though.  

Thanks!

Comment: When you use col-xs-\*, The relative width makes the content responsive. Any sol for this? Am comfortable using col-xs-\* for layouts & positions.

Answer (score 13):

Here's what worked for me:

```
<meta name='viewport' content='width=1190'>
```

I wanted a bit of a margin around my content so I also did

```
.container{
  width: 1150px !important;
}
```

Tested it on iPad and iPhone.

Comment: Sorry, this did not work in my particular case.

Answer (score 1):

I like the (accepted) solution of [@ssorallen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/368697/ssorallen). This solution don't turn of all responsive features off as asked.

The `@grid-float-breakpoint` (default at 768px) will let your menu collapse and sets the alignment of form labels based on screen width. The width of your modals and carousels depend on this setting also.

For more information, see: http://bassjobsen.weblogs.fm/compile-twitters-bootstrap-3-without-responsive-features/

**update** check the link below from @skelly too. Note this still don't change the grid-float-breakpoint neither does this solution reduce code. Further versions of TB3 will [split up some less files](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/9747) maybe. This will make it easier to compile a non-responsive version.

Comment: There is also now some guidance for this is the Bootstrap docs: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive

Comment: @Skelly. Thanks for adding this link. This solution doesn't reset the `@grid-float-breakpoint` and neither not reduce the code.

Answer (score 1):

Just search for disable all media queries and comment them out in the bootstrap.css file. It doesn't take more than a few minutes.

Then you need to set a fixed width to the outer div that sets your page content. This is usually .container in bootstrap or something like #wrapper is also common. 960px or what ever is right for your site.

You also need to remove or comment out the meta viewport tag in your HTML head. If there isn't  one then that's also fine (although you will need to add one to make if you want it responsive). It looks like this: