# Bootstrap: Change the responsive size

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on this small Bootstrap [website](http://www.grisard.ch/uferstrasse/imfoyeru90/tunesien/)   and i noticed that on some Laptop at the resolution of 768px it goes responsive. How can change the responsive breakpoint and make it NO responsive at that size?

Here some screenshots

[image: Image 1]
[image]

Comment: Remove the media queries which have the 768 px width as their upper limit.

Comment: Use the same `col- ` value for `md` and `large` .... your containers mus t be `col-md-4` as an example ... Also include your code here other way this question is useless  for future readers

Answer (score 0):

In the [customize](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) section of the bootstrap website, you can customize the media query breakpoints, to build a custom bootstrap version where the `@screen-sm` media query has a breakpoint bigger (or smaller) than 768px.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this link it may help you,[How to turn off the responsive feature completely from Twitter Bootstrap 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18146476/how-to-turn-off-the-responsive-feature-completely-from-twitter-bootstrap-3)
Change container class like this, and add this css

.container-non-responsive {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  width: 1170px;
}